# How to resolve Discrete value supplied to continuous scale and plot$scales$clone() : attempt to apply non-function ERRORS

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am currently try to automate the plotting of some scatter plots. I run into an error where I get `Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale`, `Error in Summary.factor(c(3L, 4L, 1L, 2L), na.rm = FALSE) : 
  ‘max’ not meaningful for factors` and `Error in plot$scales$clone() : attempt to apply non-function` when I try to create a pdf file with all the scatter plots. I am not sure how to resolve this issue. Below you will find my code as well as an example of one of the .csv files.

```
id,tag_name,covpercent,dayDifference, dayDifferenceHours
4404155,0.8,0.809478672985782,38 days, 22:13:21
8814971,0.9,0.83478672985782,416 days, 9:31:02
4410508,1.4,0.84838672985782,123 days, 17:49:45
7399931,1.5,0.84933272985782,301 days, 22:18:32
```

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)



csv_list = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
print(csv_list)
plot_list <- list()
for(i in 1:length(csv_list)){
  data_frame <-read.csv(csv_list[i], header =  TRUE)
  gg <- ggplot(data = data_frame , mapping = aes(x = covpercent, y = dayDifference)) +
    geom_point() +
    # Not sure if to use ylim?
    # for some reason getting the max days like this doesn't work #max(data_frame$dayDifference)
    # So I set it to 365 days
    scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,max(data_frame$dayDifference)))
    labs(x = "Code coverage",
         y = "Number of days between releases",
         title = basename(csv_list[i]) # just file name, not whole path
    )

  ggsave(filename = sub('\\.csv$', '.png', csv_list[i]), device = "png", plot = gg) # change file extension to indicate output format


  # to store plot to a list do
  #plot_list[[length(plot_list)+1]] <- gg
}

#
# Tried to produce all graphs in one pdf but I get an error
# Error in plot$scales$clone() : attempt to apply non-function

# store all plots in 1 pdf-file:

class(plot_list) <- c('arrangelist', class(ggplot()))
ggsave(file.path(dirname(csv_list[1]), 'all_plots.pdf'), plot_list, width = 25.6, height=16, units='cm', scale=1.5, dpi=1000)
```

Comment: You are missing a `+` after `scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,max(data_frame$dayDifference)))`

Comment: Also Is it because the dayDifference is formated with ints and strings for example "38 days". How do I just get the integer alone?

Comment: you should be able to call `as.numeric()` on it

Comment: And last thing. I'm not sure why this error occurs when I try to compile the graphs into a single pdf `Error in plot$scales$clone() : attempt to apply non-function`

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish with `class(plot_list) <- c('arrangelist', class(ggplot()))`?

Comment: `as.numeric() ` doesn't seem to solve it unless I'm doing it wrong.     `scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,as.numeric(max(data_frame$dayDifference))))` and when I tested print(as.numeric(data_frame$dayDifference) it truncates the number to a single digit eg 38 becomes 3

Comment: With `class(plot_list) <- c('arrangelist', class(ggplot()))` I'm trying to store all plots into a 1 pdf-file

Comment: It should be inside `max()` like this `max(as.numeric(data_frame$dayDifference))`. You may also need to call it in `ggplot()` like this `y = as.numeric(dayDifference)`.

Comment: `class(plot_list) <- c('arrangelist', class(ggplot()))` is just assigning a class to an object. In any case, saving the plots to a PDF is a separate issue from plotting the dayDifference, so it would be best to open a separate post asking that question.

Comment: I'm so sorry but I'm new to R... I don't know if you saw my edited comment about the truncation and now it tells me that `Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale`

Comment: Ok thank you for the help with regards to the pdf. I might just scrap that all together and just focus on the individual scatter plots

Comment: Actually I figure out the `Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale` But I'm unsure why it truncates the values to single digits tho

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191826/discussion-between-wil-and-alongtest12).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now `dayDifference` is class "difftime". You have to convert it to numeric. This should generate your individual plots:

```r
data_frame <-read.csv(csv_list[i], header =  TRUE)
data_frame$dayDifference <- as.numeric(gsub("[^[:digit:]]","",data_frame$dayDifference))
gg <- ggplot(data = data_frame , mapping = aes(x = covpercent, y = dayDifference)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,max(data_frame$dayDifference))) +
  labs(x = "Code coverage",
       y = "Number of days between releases",
       title = basename(csv_list[i])
  )

gg
```

Comment: Works fine. Only thing I can't figure why as.numeric keeps on truncating the numbers for example in my .csv file "38 days, 416 days, etc" get truncated to "3,4, ...." The graph doesn't have the correct numbers for y-axis which is weird

Comment: I thought it was an object of class `difftime` but it is a literal string. I have edited my answer to supply the correct conversion. Let me know if that works.